# Can Email Notification of Find my iPhone be disabled?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

When I use the Find my iPhone for my daughter's phone she receives and e-mail telling her that someone has been using find my iPhone to locate her phone. Can the email notification be disabled ?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, it can't. If you want to track an iOS device without an email notification, try Apple's Find My Friends.