# How to turn on email notifications when Find My iPhone is used?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

I actually liked getting email notifications when Find My iPhone was used and all of the sudden they stopped. I can't find any options to turn them back on. Anyone know why they stopped or how to get them back?

Answer (score 1):

[You can't turn off email notifications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150272/can-email-notification-of-find-my-iphone-be-disabled), so they are being sent, but not being delivered. Check that the email address is correct and the emails are not being delivered to your spam folder.